# rospy publisher hanging when subscriber drops connection because of wifi - is this normal?

Tags: ros, wifi, rospy, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a visualizer running on a laptop via a wifi connection subscribing to GPS messages.  When the wifi is dropped the gps publisher hangs (preventing vehicle control through other subscribers).  When the wifi is reestablished the publisher continues where it left off.

Is this normal? - how do ensure the vehicle code runs independently of any wifi based subscribers?  Is this rospy specific behavior?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29387/rospy-publisher-hanging-when-subscriber-drops-connection-because-of-wifi---is-this-normal?/) by [Johnny](https://answers.ros.org/users/1937/johnny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-03-08**:
Are you using a topic, or a service?

**Comment by [Johnny](https://answers.ros.org/users/1937/johnny/) on 2012-03-14**:
topics.  I have duplicated my issue with the talker listener tutorials.  e.g. start both roscpp and rospy talkers (publishing to the same chatter topic), and on a wirelessly connected pc start a (either) listener, drop the connection, and later (~1 minute) the rospy publisher hangs, roscpp still OK.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-03-15**:
It might be worth taking this question to ros-users, as it sounds like you might have triggered a real bug. (I was *really* hoping the answers was services; because services are synchronous, that would explain your problem)

**Comment by [Advait Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/219/advait-jain/) on 2013-02-07**:
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have opened a ticket for this:
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/169

---

Originally posted by [Advait Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/219/advait-jain/) with karma: 140 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0